# FB login not working in Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I can't log to Facebook using the JSDK api. I've read it was common in Chrome to have issues with blocked popups however the popup opens fine and to the user there is no apparent issue. However I get the console log "Unsafe Javascript Access" and the user is not logged in.

I added a Login event for debugging in Chrome with is not fired at all.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '247886858583094',
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    oauth      : true,
  });
     FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',function(response) { alert('You logged in'); } );
};
(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
```

I tried with a blank HTML page and only this and the login button, so it's definitely a problem on part of the browser or the api.

Anyone came across this issue? Any solutions?

Comment: Where's the code that actually logs the user in? Like calling *FB.login* or something? Also, have you checked that it works fine in other browsers but Chrome?

Comment: Did you try subscribing to the auth.statusChange event? Unless I'm mistaken, specifying "status:true" in your init will fire the statusChange event on load. FB.login, as Nitzan pointed out, will trigger the auth.login event.